# Equalities with 2 given substitions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be real numbers such that $\alpha + \beta = 1$ and $-\alpha\beta = 1$ Which of the following equalities hold?

> A. $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 2$

> B. $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = 3$

> C. $\alpha^4 + \beta^4 = 6$

> D. $\alpha^5 + \beta^5 = 12$

> E. $\alpha^6 + \beta^6 = 18$

My attempts of solving this problem:

A.$$ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 2 $$

> $$\alpha^2 + (-2\ \alpha \cdot \beta) + \beta^2 + 2\ \alpha\cdot\beta$$
> $$=\left(\alpha + \beta \right)^2 + \left( -2\ \alpha\beta \right)  $$
> We already know that $\alpha + \beta = 1$ and $-\alpha\beta = 1$ which implies the following equation :
> $1^2 + 2 \cdot 1= 3$

> So we can conclude A isn't the answer

B.

> $$\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = \left(\alpha +\beta \right)\left(\alpha^2 - \alpha\beta + \beta^2 \right)$$
> $$1\cdot \left(3 + 1)\right) =4 $$

So B is neither the right answer.

For the following multiple choices I can't get to the final answer. Could someone help me with this?

Kind regards in advance.

Comment: you can find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ using the quadratic formula

Comment: For example for $\alpha^4 + \beta^4$ one will get $\left(\alpha + \beta)\right) $ $\left(\alpha^3-\alpha^2\beta + \alpha\beta^2 - \beta^3\right)$.  But I don't know how to simplify this even with the quadratic formula.

Comment: @Anonymous196 $\alpha,\beta$ are the roots of $t^2-t-1=0$ so $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$ and $\,\beta^2=\beta+1\,$. Multiplying by the $(n-1)^{th}$ powers and adding up $s_{n+1}=\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}=(\alpha^n+\beta^n)+(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})=s_n+s_{n-1}$ so you can calculate all sums recursively starting from $s_0=2, s_1=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\alpha$ and $y=\beta$. We have:
$$x^4+y^4=(x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2y^2=3^2-2=7$$
And:
$$x^6+y^6=(x^3+y^3)^2-2x^3y^3=4^2-2\cdot(-1)=16+2=18$$
So, the correct answer is E.

Comment: How does one simplify the 4th answer?

Comment: @Anonymous16: it's a sum of fifth power. You can factor in the following way: $$x^5-y^5=(x-y)\cdot(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)$$But this I think it is not goig to help... You must what I call "eye"... And you obtain it with expirience.

Comment: That's what I've already gotten. I was wondering if it might be plausible to do something with answer 1 and 2 to get a simplified answer for this.

Comment: @Anonymous196 Look up [Newton's identities](https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/). EG $ x^{n+2} + y^{n+2} = (x+y) ( x^{n+1} + y^{n+1} ) - xy (x^n + y^n) $. Hence these values can be determined recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Choice E. Use $\alpha^6+\beta^6 = (\alpha^3+\beta^3)^2 -2(\alpha\beta)^3 = 4^2 - 2(-1) = 18$.